# terminate thread windows in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm having some trouble terminating some threads for a lab I have to do.

I believe I've got everything else working, but the trouble comes at the end. So basically, we need to have two threads running, a top window that counts up, and a bottom window that counts down. What we're supposed to have happen is that when you enter a keyboard click, one window will stop counting. When you enter a second click, the other window will also stop counting. Once they both stop, there is a three second delay, after which the program will terminate.

The problem is that once I enter a button click, both windows stop counting, and then I have to forcefully terminate the program. Can anyone see what I'm not doing right?

```
/*
Godfried Weihs
Lab 5
CS3100
*/

#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

WINDOW *topwin, *botwin;

//mutex
pthread_mutex_t ncurses = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_t thread1, thread2;

void * countUp(void *ptr) {
int i = 0, key;

while (1) {
    //thread lock
    pthread_mutex_lock(&ncurses);
    wprintw(topwin, "Count up: %d\n", i++);
    wrefresh(topwin);
    key = getch();
    if (key != ERR) {
        break;
    }
    //thread unlock
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ncurses);
}
return NULL;
}

void * countDown(void *ptr) {
int i = 0, key;

while (1) {
    //thread lock
    pthread_mutex_lock(&ncurses);
    wprintw(botwin, "Count down: %d\n", i--);
    wrefresh(botwin);
    key = getch();
    if (key != ERR) {
        break;
    }
    //thread unlock
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ncurses);
}
return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int tlines, blines;

//thread lock
pthread_mutex_lock(&ncurses);
initscr();
cbreak();
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
noecho();
nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
tlines = LINES/2-1;
blines = LINES-tlines-1;
//thread unlock
pthread_mutex_unlock(&ncurses); 


//thread lock
pthread_mutex_lock(&ncurses);   
topwin = newwin(tlines, COLS, 0, 0);
//thread unlock
pthread_mutex_unlock(&ncurses);
scrollok(topwin, TRUE);

//thread lock
pthread_mutex_lock(&ncurses);
botwin = newwin(blines, COLS, tlines+1, 0);
//thread unlock
pthread_mutex_unlock(&ncurses);
scrollok(botwin, TRUE);

move(tlines, 0);
if (has_colors()) {
    //thread lock
    pthread_mutex_lock(&ncurses);
    start_color();
    init_pair(1, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(3, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_BLACK);
    wattron(topwin, COLOR_PAIR(1));
    wattron(botwin, COLOR_PAIR(2));
    wattron(stdscr, COLOR_PAIR(3));
    //thread unlock
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ncurses);
}
hline('_', 200);
refresh();

// Thread code goes HERE!
pthread_create(&thread1, (pthread_attr_t *) NULL,
            (void *) countUp, (void *) NULL);

pthread_create(&thread2, (pthread_attr_t *) NULL,
            (void *) countDown, (void *) NULL);     

//thread termination
pthread_join(thread1, (void *) NULL);
pthread_join(thread2, (void *) NULL);   

usleep(3000000);
endwin();   

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you break from your infinite loops, you are neglecting to unlock the ncurses mutex, so the other thread deadlocks. You should use e.g.

```
if (key != ERR) {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ncurses);
    break;
}
```

It's best if you can place your locks and unlocks in such a way that you never mess up. For example,

```
bool running = true;
do {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&ncurses);
    running = do_stuff();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ncurses);
} while(running);
```

Now the `do_stuff()` function can just early out by returning false whenever it wants, without worrying about mutexes.

Comment: I played around with it. I needed to unlock before that if statement. Thank you!

Comment: With my original suggestion you would have had to leave the original `pthread_mutex_unlock` in place as well :)